# C# Check if DataGridView Contains specific word

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors, contains

I'm currently working on an IRC bot. The sent messages will be shown in a DataGridView. So now I want to check if for example the sent message contains a specific word. Let's say "test".

So it should check for the following:

Let's say the sent message, which is added to the DataGridView is: My name is test.

Now the Cell, which contains the word "test" should get colored red.

I already solved this, when the message ONLY contains "test". But I don't really know how to check for a word in a sentence.

//Edit: I tried this code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
      if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "test")
          row.Cells["chat1"].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
          //row.Cells["chat1"].Style.ForeColor = Color.CadetBlue;
}
```

Kind Regards,
Max :)

Comment: please post your code what you tried so that we can help with you;  As a matter of fact, you can test your yourStringVariable.Contains(stringToCheck)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added my code in the question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check with Contains to verify the string presence anywhere in the given input.  You may consider to apply `ToLower` or `ToUpper` methods before checking `Contains` to ensure proper results

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
     if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains("test"))
        row.Cells["chat1"].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        //row.Cells["chat1"].Style.ForeColor = Color.CadetBlue;
}
```

Comment: Oh god.. What an easy fix.. I think this was a brain error on my side haha.. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 3):

you can also practice using [linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) to solve this problem

```
 var items = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
             .Where(row => row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "Test");

 foreach(DataGridViewRow row in items)
 {
      row.Cells["chat1"].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
 }
```